# Account info on Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching far and wide, and cannot for the life of me find the answer.

I'm trying to put PHP login info (Welcome *user* / My Account / Logout) on the bootstrap navbar, but no matter what I do, I can't get it to align on the left next to the navitems instead of above!

Location of the items [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBZww.png)

This is the code I have right now:

```
<header id="mainHeader" class="navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
<div class="container">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse scrollMenu" role="navigation">
     <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button> </div>                         <a class="brand">
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="scrollTarget">
     <div>
        <p class="brand"><div class="welcome">Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username']; ?><br/><a href="?action=account">My Account</a> | <a href="?logout">Logout</a></div></p></div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="?action=projects"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i>Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="?action=clients"><i class="icon-users"></i>Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="?action=admins"><i class="icon-user"></i>Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="?action=settings"><i class="icon-wrench"></i>Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        </nav>
 </div>
</header>
```

can anyone tell me where to move the code, or what to modify to get it to line up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using divs inside of your brand, which have block layout by default. They're going to push surrounding content to the next line. You should probably be using spans or anchors, which have an inline layout by default.

Here's some working code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mH82S/2/))...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <p class="navbar-text"><span class="welcome">Welcome, username</span> <br><a href="#" class="navbar-link">My Account</a> | <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Logout</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The bootstrap examples are very helpful.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-text

Comment: sorry for the week-late comment, thank you so much for taking the time to answer and explain, really helped me out :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped welcome user text in own div with `col-sm-6` which did the trick. Ofcourse you might want to fix positioning on mobile menu with this..

```
    <header id="mainHeader" class="navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse scrollMenu" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="scrollTarget">
                <div>
                    <div class="brand col-sm-6">
                        <div class="welcome">Welcome,user<br/>
                            <a href="?action=account">My Account</a> | 
                            <a href="?logout">Logout</a></div></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right ">
                        <li><a href="?action=projects"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i>Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?action=clients"><i class="icon-users"></i>Clients</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?action=admins"><i class="icon-user"></i>Admin</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?action=settings"><i class="icon-wrench"></i>Settings</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked :) You saved me quite a headache.

Comment: @Rhendera I'd suggest using the navbar-right class on your menu, rather than the pull-right class. It will be properly aligned on mobile. The col-sm-6 is also going to break on mobile. See the other answer for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, turned out to be even easier than mentioned answers above. (although those work too!)

```
<div><p class="navbar-text">Login info/text here</p></div
```

was all it took. navbar-brand is for images, that was what I was doing wrong.